# mysql select where greater than less than multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I have a column that has month and years as columns.. I need to select a range out of the columns.. they don't seem to work with 2 ranges.

Table

```
CREATE TABLE `sampletable` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `AccountId` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `CampaignId` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `CampaignName` varchar(115) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Sent` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Month` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Year` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `LocationId` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `AccountId_idx` (`AccountId`),
  KEY `monthy_year_idx` (`Month`,`Year`),
  KEY `locationid_idx` (`LocationId`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1584
```

Select statement:

```
SELECT * FROM sampletable
WHERE AccountId = 1 
and (`Month` >= 10 AND `Year` = 2012)
and (`Month` <= 2 AND `Year` = 2013)
ORDER BY Year asc, month asc
```

This does not seem to work.

Do I have to convert these into date formats and use between?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are doing is something similar to "trying to go left and right at the same time".

Lets break the `WHERE` clause.

You are telling `MySQL` to get rows with

1. `Year = 2012 AND Year = 2013`
2. `Month >= 10 AND Month <= 2`

This will never be true.

Your `WHERE` clause should look like  -

```
WHERE AccountId = 1 
and ((`Month` >= 10 AND `Year` = 2012)
OR (`Month` <= 2 AND `Year` = 2013))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 and (     
  (`Month` >= 10 AND `Year` = 2012)
 or (`Month` <= 2 AND `Year` = 2013))
```

Answer (score 1):

enclose the condition around parenthesis and use `OR`

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE AccountId = 1  AND   
      ((`Month` >= 10 AND `Year` = 2012) OR  (`Month` <= 2 AND `Year` = 2013) )
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want  use 'or' instead of 'and'.